# Запятая и тире?

Tags: пунктуация, запятая-и-тире

Правильно я понимаю, что нужен единый знак?

`Стоит персонажу сказать что-нибудь, — сразу происходит какое-то действие обратное его словам.`

А так?

`Как только персонаж скажет какое-то слово(, —) сразу произойдëт какое-либо действие обратное его словам.`

Можно ли во втором ставить единый знак, чтобы подчеркнуть самостоятельность обоих частей? Думаю, можно. Единый знак тоже в какой-то степени подчëркивает самостоятельность.

Answer (score 2):

Тире понятно и законно, а запятая-то зачем?

Я очень люблю зап-тире как единый знак, но применяю его не чтобы "в какой-то степени подчеркнуть самостоятельность", а только при "переломе конструкции" (про прямую речь опустим), где я, как автор, хозяйка (если не перелом, то вывих), —

но тут-то зап излишня, зато её нет где надо:

*Стоит персонажу сказать что-нибудь — сразу происходит какое-то действие, обратное его словам.*

*Как только персонаж скажет какое-то слово — сразу произойдëт какое-либо действие, обратное его словам.*

Не вижу никакой разницы в структуре двух предложений ("А так?").

Comment: Мне кажется, подойдëт случай из справочника Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_46.htm

Comment: @Максим Указывайте, пожалуйста, что за случай, а то приходится читать весь параграф. Если вы о переломе конструкции, то его совсем нет. Части предельно взаимосвязаны. Я полностью согласен с Галиной: одного тире достаточно. И с запятой перед перед определением в постпозиции тоже.

Comment: Максим, я уже старенькая Розенталя читать. ))) Моим вузовским педагогом была Валгина.

Comment: Вы что по Розенталю, что по Валгиной – всегда хороши)

Comment: Оой... Во всех я, душенька, нарядах хороша... Иди глянь, чиво я давеча натворила: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4300109-uzhe-ja-ne-chitaju-knig-i-ne-smotrju-kino-pochtenie-k-prochteniju-zaversheno.html#answer12215498 и http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4299004-pochemu-kommentarii-inogda-byvajut-interesnee-otveta.html#answer12215350

Comment: И http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4299181-kakaja-trebuetsja-slovu-sila-chtob-slovo-izrechennoe-ozhilo.html#answer12213093 и http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4295514-s-kakimi-znamenitymi-ljudmi-vy-znalis-ili-hotja-by-soprikasalis.html#answer12204055

Comment: И http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4038459-nikto-ne-objazan-znat-vseh-vtorostepennyh-poetov-o-kom-idjot-rech.html#answer12201900 и http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4293807-stihija-stiha-est-istina-v-nej-ili-tolko-chepuha.html#answer12200247 и http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/4291839-kuda-delis-dvorovye-pesni.html#answer12197226